# Return arraylist populated inside Callback

Tags: java, android, arraylist, twitter

I'm trying to use an arraylist of Tweets that has been populated inside a callback but I can't figure out how to return the built list.  Whenever I try to use the built list it's empty.

I got some code from this [post](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/30518639/get-list-of-tweets-in-user-time-line-using-fabric-android)

```
public  ArrayList<Tweet> tweetList() { 
   final ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<>();
   final UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder()
           .screenName("xxxxxxxx")
           .build();
   userTimeline.next(null, new Callback<TimelineResult<Tweet>>() {
       @Override
       public void success(Result<TimelineResult<Tweet>> result) {
           for(Tweet tweet : result.data.items){
               tweets.add(tweet);
           }
           Log.d("Finished Tweet List", String.valueOf(tweets));
           //  when this is printed I can see the ArrayList and all tweets are there
       }
       @Override
       public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
           exception.printStackTrace();
       }
   });
   Log.d("Tweet list returned", String.valueOf(tweets));
   // the value of tweets is empty here for some reason

   return tweets;
}
```

Comment: Since the information is returned via a callback, I'm guessing that the method is asynchronous. If that's the case then your method is starting another thread to access the internet and returning before that callback is fired. Put the work you want to do inside the callback to ensure that the information was properly delivered.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of returning the empty `ArrayList` of `Tweet`s, you can modify your method so another `ArrayList` of `Tweet`s is updated when the response from the `Callback` succeeds.

So I suggest modifying your method as follows:

```
private ArrayList<Tweet> tweetList = new ArrayList<>();

public void tweetList() { 
   final ArrayList<Tweet> tweets = new ArrayList<>();
   final UserTimeline userTimeline = new UserTimeline.Builder()
           .screenName("xxxxxxxx")
           .build();
   userTimeline.next(null, new Callback<TimelineResult<Tweet>>() {
       @Override
       public void success(Result<TimelineResult<Tweet>> result) {
           for(Tweet tweet : result.data.items){
               tweets.add(tweet);
           }

           this.tweetList = tweets;

           // execute the next sequence of instructions in your program here
           // and make use of tweetList instead of tweets

       }

       @Override
       public void failure(TwitterException exception) {
           exception.printStackTrace();
       }
   });
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Of course, the value of tweets is empty here !
The function `userTimeline.next(null, new Callback<TimelineResult<Tweet>>()` is not executed on the main thread (It is an asynchronous task).
So the `return tweets` is called before your `ArrayList<Tweets> tweets` has been filled.

You can only do operations on your list in the

```
@Override
public void success(Result<TimelineResult<Tweet>> result) {
   //do whatever with your list here !
}
```

Hope I'll have been clear !